# Calculating change in a program - Floating point error

Tags: java, eclipse, methods

I've been working on making a program to calculate change and the program never ends up running and terminating after completion. I don't know what's wrong with my code. If anyone could help that'd be great.

```
private static void calculateChange(double price, double given) {
    int ones = 0, quarters = 0, dimes = 0, nickels = 0, pennies = 0;
    double change = given - price;
    while (change != 0) {
        if (change >= 1) {
            change = change - 1;
            ones++;
        }
        if (change >= .25) {
            change = change - 0.25;
            quarters++;
        }
        if (change >= .10) {
            change = change - .10;
            dimes++;
        }
        if (change >= .05) {
            change = change - .05;
            nickels++;
        }
        if (change >= .01) {
            change = change - .01;
            pennies++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Correct Change");
    System.out.println("Ones " + ones);
    System.out.println("Quarters  " + quarters);
    System.out.println("Dimes " + dimes);
    System.out.println("Nickels " + nickels);
    System.out.println("Pennies " + pennies);

}
```

Comment: Do not use floating point values for a program like this.  Use integers (pennies) instead.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've made the coins as Integers but it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you debug it? Change is probably becoming less than 0, which you're allowing.

Comment: @Asker123 When I say to use pennies, what I mean is to use pennies for everything.  A dollar is 100, a quarter is 25, a nickel is 5, etc.  So your calculations will not use `double` at all, instead it will be using purely integer arithmetic, which is exact (see the answers below).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Got it. But why does Java do this. Why does this happen with doubles and not ints?

Comment: @Asker123 [See this link and read it carefully](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). This is a must for anyone wishing to be a computer programmer and has to deal with calculations like this.  Money and financial calculations are in many instances required to compute exact values, thus using `double` for this is a definite no-go.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Good read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `double` type is [floating point](http://floating-point-gui.de/), and floating point numbers trade precision for performance.  At some point, when you are subtracting cents from `change`, it becomes less than 0.01 but greater than zero, *or* it becomes less than zero.

In either of these cases, all of your `if` conditionals will be false, but the `while` conditional still holds true, resulting in an infinite loop.

A quick solution would be to change your `while` condition from `change != 0` to `change >= 0.01`.

A better solution would be to use an integral number type (such as `int`) and have it store the number of cents (so a dollar would be 100).  This approach will not have any floating-point number inaccuracies.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for that. I also made sure to add pennies++ because the change will always contain one less penny.

Answer (score 2):

Numbers like 0.1, 0.05 or 0.01 cannot be represented exactly as binary floating point numbers. Therefore your `change` probably never becomes zero.

Aside from using integers or BCD, you could allow a tolerance when checking for zero, for example

```
while (Math.abs(change) < 0.000001) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is a floating point issue.  Your double precision "change" will never excactly equal integer zero, thus your "while" test will always evauate true.  Try doing something along the lines of 
while(change >= epsilon)

Also... try using an if else-if chain...